# Ruby base64 encode png can not display in android browser

Tags: ruby, png, base64

When I use ruby to encode png to base4, it can not be displayed in android mobile browser. someting like below:

```
File.open(real_path, "rb") {|io| io.read}
```

I use Base64:encode64 method, also doesn't work.....

I find the encoded string is end up with "YII==", but other worked frame work encode the png
 end up with "g==". Is this a clue to solve this problem?

Who can give me a way to encode the png working on android browser?